# rails calling an image in my assets file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I have created a simple form with 2 columns: Product and image. They are both string variables and I want to be able to store a name for the product and in the image column a location of a picture which is stored in my `apps/assets/images` folder.
 
The problem is getting the image to appear in my view table. I tried entering 
  `<%=image_tag("dvd.jpg", alt: "Product")%>` as an input to the form but this just shows it as a string any help to fix this problem will be appreciated im still getting my head around rails.

Comment: Which gem are you using to store image>

Comment: What does your view look like? I think you only need to store "dvd.jpg" and then in your view do something like `<%= image_tag(@object.image, alt: "Product") %>`.

Comment: hi Ganesh im just storing a link to the image in the database then i want to call link in my view which will show the picture cant seem to figure it out

Comment: Basically i want to have a few pictures in my image folder then when im entering a new product enter a link to the images and then be able to show it in my view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i figured out what i was looking for first type rails generate scaffold Product title:string image_url:string......then in app/viewsproducts/_form.html.erb for the image_url type:

> `<div class="field"> <%= f.label :image_url %></br> <%= f.text_field
>   :image_url %> </div>`

then when your entering a image_url in your form type: /assets/pic_name.jpg. make sure the picture is saved in the assets/images folder. 
the view code looks like this `<%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>`

Thanks for above help

Answer (score 0):

```
= image_tag @product.picture.url if @product.picture?
```

Comment: hi i tried your suggestion   <%= image_tag @product.picture.url if @product.picture? %>  in my view does not seem to show picture after i entered  the following input into database <%=image_tag("dvd.jpg", alt: "Product")%> any other ideas

Comment: Do you want that the picture be shown in real time, or after submit form?

Comment: After it has been submitted to database so when i write in my form <%=image_tag("dvd.jpg", alt: "Product")%> or another picture <%=image_tag("game.jpg", alt: "Product")%> and i call them from my database like a normal database call <td><%= Product.image %></td> the image will appear and not the link string